# Insert into BQ one nested table into another different nested table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to copy one nested BigQuery table into another nested table and am running into the following error Query column 2 has type ARRAY<STRUCT<Name STRING, Value STRING>> which cannot be inserted into column request, which has type STRUCT<properties ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, value STRING

Query:

```
INSERT INTO `<GCP_PROJECT_NAME>.Test_Tables.Nested_Person_Table2` 
  (cinema,
  director.movie.Name,
  director.movie.Budget)
SELECT
  cinema,
  movie.Name,
  movie.Budget
FROM
`<GCP_PROJECT_NAME>.Dataset.Table`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't insert partial struct. You need to provide the full struct in your BigQuery table (that is going to change in the future with a new JSON friendly engine)

```
INSERT INTO `<GCP_PROJECT_NAME>.Test_Tables.Nested_Person_Table2` 
  (cinema,
  director)
SELECT
  cinema,
  STRUCT(movie as director)
FROM
`<GCP_PROJECT_NAME>.Dataset.Table`
```

---

**EDIT1**

You can't insert partial data. you need to insert the full object in each line

```
INSERT INTO `<GCP_PROJECT_NAME>.Test_Tables.Nested_Person_Table2` 
  (cinema,
  director)
SELECT
  cinema,
  STRUCT([STRUCT(mo.Name as Name, mo.Budget as Budget)] as movie, "" as language, "" as English, "" as other, STRUCT("","") as source) as director
FROM
`<GCP_PROJECT_NAME>.Dataset.Table`, UNNEST(movie) as mo
```

*PS: Language shouldn't be a record in your target table with english and other in it?*

Comment: Its not working. again throwing the same error

Comment: Can you share the schema of the 2 tables. I tested on my side on dummy table, and it worked.

Comment: I have added in the question. Please have a look at it once

Comment: Updated my answer, with the schema it's easier, and more relevant!! Let me know

Comment: Excellent..Its working.Thank You

Comment: I have made couple of changes in schema. So that it can accepts many changes. Could you please help me on that.

Comment: I want to phrase the target table for language in below format [{'English': None, 'Other': 'spanish'}] and the entire list has to load as a record to language column